cordova-plugin-barcodescanner crashing after scan on Android
cordova-plugin-barcodescanner crashing after scan on Android.
Camera launches. Able to capture text from barcode and print to log. App then crashes and goes to login page.
barcodescanner works as expected on iOS.
Any help would be much appreciated.
METEOR@2.15
Cordova 7
SDK 33
AngularJS
@red-mobile/cordova-plugin-barcodescanner@9.1.0
Logs are extensive but nothing standing out.

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<label class="item item-input item-range" ng-click="cameraView.scanQRCode()"> <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" class="item-container qr-code-container"> <i class="icon ion-ios-qr-scanner-outline qr-code-icon"></i> </div> </label>
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan
Tried every variant of cordova barcode scanner that will compile with same behavior across board.
Expecting app to return to view where launched from and not crash. It does return for split second but then crashes.

Please look through the logs for some exception and add it to your post. Otherwise it will be difficult to help without knowing whats wrong. Also some more code would be useful. Maybe your implementation is causing the issue, similar to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59554181/android-app-crashing-when-trying-to-scan-barcode

FYI - Issue is that on Android when camera shuts down it issues "resume" event which triggered the below. Removing makes everything work.
document.addEventListener("resume", function(){
viewService.nextDirection = 'back';
$state.go('login');

}, false);
